# Dependency Injection container for functional programming in Typescript and Express

Tags: typescript, express, dependency-injection, functional-programming, ioc-container

Is there any dependency injection container like InversifyJs but for functional programming in typescript? What I want to achieve is to inject a fake function from my tests end to end in the same way that i do with the OOP like the following example

Test end to end binding fake user repository

```
import magicContainer from 'magic-library'
import { UserRepositoryInterface } from '..'
import { FakeUserRepository } from '..'

describe(‘My test describe’, () => {

    test('My test', async () => {
        magicContainer.bind(UserRepositoryInterface, FakeUserRepository)

        await supertest(app)
        .post('/my-endpoint')
        .send({payload})
        .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
})

})
```

Express Router:

```
import {UserRepositoryInterface} from '...'
import {UserRepository} from '...'
import magicContainer from ‘magic-library’

const router = Router()
router.post('/my-endpoint', magicContainer.bind(UserRepositoryInterface, UserRepository)
)
```

User Interface and implementations:

```
export interface UserRepositoryInterface {
    myFunction: () => Promise<User[]>
}


export const UserRepository: UserRepositoryInterface = {
    myFunction: async () => {
        …
    }
}

export const FakeUserRepository: UserRepositoryInterface = {
    myFunction: async () => {
        …
    }
}
```

I have tried with libraries like [InversifyJS](https://inversify.io/), [tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#injectable) and [node-dependency-injection](https://github.com/zazoomauro/node-dependency-injection) but they are purely object oriented, not for functional programming

Comment: I don't have experience with typescript. `Dependency Injection` is just a design pattern mostly used in `OOP`. You have a class, you have some dependencies on other classes that you general "inject" during the construction of the object. The dependencies could be passed in the constructor, using a builder pattern, a decorator, etc. In functional programming, you don't have exactly dependencies. You have a function that receives parameters (could be values or other functions) and you return a value or a function. Pass a function as a parameter could be similar to dependency injection

Comment: You might find some luck with `iti`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/iti
Disclaimer: author here :)

Comment: Since dependency injection in FP is just passing arguments to functions, I find there's no real need for a library to do this. I just instantiate functions with mock dependencies manually in tests

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem before, some people argue that dependency injection is a design pattern that should be implemented in OOP only however this is not right, dependency injection and dependency inversion are principles can be applied on both functional programming and OOP
The idea is very simple but first we should know the main components for dependency injection:

- dependency
- dependency consumer
- DC/dependency container
  Regarding the dependency consumer, in OOP you have a constructor that you inject dependencies in however in FP you don't have that so you just need to inject a function inside a function, how can you do that?
  Thanks to javascript closures and higher order functions, using them you can implement a higher order function that receives the dependencies you need and returns a function that holds the concrete implementation
  so basically the higher-order function plays the constructor role.
  The third thing you need is the dependency injection container and this can be done using some data structure and algorithm to hold all your dependencies and pick the right one when it's required.
  I created a library for that purpose you can check it, I am using it currently on production and works very well
  https://github.com/tareksalem/injectx

Example:

1- create a dependency:

```js
export class DB {
  users = [
    {
      username: "John",
    }
  ]
}
export const db = new DB();
```

2- Create a Dependency Consumer

```js
export const GetUserRepository = ({ db }: { db: DB }) => (username: string) => {
    return db.users.find(user => user.username === username)
}
export const getUserReposistory = InjectIn(GetUserRepository)
```

3- bind the dependencies into the container

```js
import { GetContainer } from "injectx"
import { db } from "./db"
import { GetUserRepository } from "./getUser.repository";

export const DiInit = () => {
  GetContainer('default').Bind(db, { name: 'db' }).Bind(GetUserRepository);
}
```